# Как получить все строки таблицы поочередно в массив?

Tags: php, mysql

Как получить все строки таблицы поочередно в массив?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$q = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table');
$res = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $res[] = $r;
}

print_r($res);
```

Comment: расширение mysql устарело.

Comment: @eicto, ровно на одну букву?